# Optimizing a geometrical algorithm [ points inside a region inside a circle ]

Tags: python, algorithm, data-structures, geometry, time-complexity

This is from a coding assessment. The problem is as such:

> A node is a point on the x-y plane (i, j) where i,j are integers. Given a circle with radius `R` originating from `(xl, yl)` and a rectangular grid with bottom left coordinate (x1, y1) and top right coordinate (x2, y2), write a program that returns the number of nodes within the grid that are contained within (or on the perimeter of) the circle.

I wrote this program:

```
def numPointsInCircle(x1, y1, x2, y2, xl, yl, R):
  num = 0
  for x in range(x1, x2 + 1):
    for y in range(y1, y2 + 1):
      if (x - xl) ** 2 + (y - yl) ** 2 <= R ** 2:
        num += 1
  return num
```

The logic is: the loop gives all `(x, y)` "nodes" within the rectangular grid, and for each one, we test whether their distance from the center of the circle is greater than the radius.

I passed 9/15 test cases and failed the rest due to time limit exceeded. How can this be optimized to be more efficient?

Some things I tried:

- restricting the grid for the top right to be at most the circle's top right and the bottom right to be at most the circle's bottom right
- early break conditions when `(x - xl)` or `(y - yl)` alone surpasses the `R`

Comment: In many languages, `foo ** 2` is more expensive than you might think, because it actually means exp(2 ln *foo*). Just changing that to `foo * foo` can be a significant speedup (though it probably won't be enough of a speedup in your case; your coding assessment wants you to choose a faster algorithm).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that we don't need to check every point inside rect or circle but we can calculate number of needed points in every integer scan line

[image]

So we walk through possible `Y` values in range and sum valid points. What is `Y` range? Low border of range is higher value (maximum) of rectangle bottom and bottom point of the circle: `max(y1, yl-R)`. High end of range is minimum from rectangle top and circle top: `min(y2+1, yl+R+1)`

For horizontal line at coordinate `Y` half-width of circle is `dx=int(sqrt(R*R-(Y-yl)*(Y-yl)))`. And left grid point of scanline is `l=max(x1, xl-dx)`, right one is `r=min(x2, xl+dx)`, so scanline contains `r-l+1` grid points.

We reduce complexity from `O(width*height)` to `O(min(R, rectangle_height)`

For Python >= 3.8 use `math.isqrt` function

```
from math import sqrt

def ptsincircleandrect(x1, y1, x2, y2, xl, yl, R):
    cnt = 0
    for Y in range(max(y1, yl-R), min(y2+1, yl+R+1)):
        dx = int(sqrt(R*R-(Y-yl)*(Y-yl)))
        cnt += max(0, 1 + min(x2, xl+dx) - max(x1, xl-dx))
    return cnt
```

Random tests (two last values should be equal):

```
from random import randint  
x1 = randint(-2,6)
x2 = x1 + randint(1,6)
y1 = randint(-2,6)
y2 = x1 + randint(1,6)
xl = randint(-3,7)
yl = randint(-3,7)
R = randint(2,6)

print(x1,y1,x2,y2,xl,yl,R, ptsincircleandrect(x1, y1, x2, y2, xl, yl, R), numPointsInCircle(x1, y1, x2, y2, xl, yl, R))

-1 -2 2 1 -2 1 4 12 12
```

Comment: Could you please place this answer in the context of the problem? It's hard to understand as is and I don't quite get it.

Comment: Yes, to be clear: (xl, yl) is center of circle, and (x1, y1) is bottom right of the rectangle and (x2, y2) is top right.

Comment: I don't quite understand it. I've been trying to study it, but the calculation for how many grid points we have is unclear and also the math you did in your function. Sorry, but I cannot understand it without comments.

Comment: I added more description.Does picture help?

Comment: I think it should be `range(max(yl - R, y1), min(yl + R, y2) + 1)`

Comment: I am trying to figure out what is going on in the function with the scan line still.

Comment: Ok. Here is my understanding: we get the minimum range of possible y-values which fit inside both so we are not wasting time with y's that have no chance. then, we get `dx` which is `x - xl`, but the calculation here is interesting because I think `xl + dx` gives us `x`, the maximum possible x in the circle, and `-xl - dx` gives us `-x`, the minimum possible one, or we could just take the negative. I am not sure of your calculation. I think what this says is we can be at most `abs(xl + dx)` away from `xl` and still be in circle for that scan line.

Comment: `cnt = 0
    for y in range(max(yl - R, y1), min(yl + R, y2) + 1):
        dx = isqrt(R ** 2 + (y - yl) ** 2)
        d = xl + dx
        cnt += 1 + min(x2, xl + d) - max(x1, xl - d) 
    return cnt`

Comment: I think there needs to be an additional condition checking for the `min(...) - max(...)` to be positive, for example, in the case where the circle and the rectangle are disjoint

Comment: I will spend more time, but I truly do not get the `range` where you do `R` without taking into account `yl`

Comment: OK, tests passed

Comment: I think my code is correct too if `d` is replaced with `dx`, but I’m not 100% certain

Comment: Yes, it will be the same code if we remove d and replace d by dx

Comment: I think I understand then. So the way the `range` was before was a mistake or was that an alternate solution?

Comment: In revision 3-5 (look ar edit history) I shifted all coordinates to make formulas simpler (without xl, yl). Later (revision 6)  I removed shift, but lost some corrections

Comment: Got it. Thanks. The current way makes sense to me

Answer (score 0):

The following is (purposefully) a mere optimization of your existing code, i.e. not on an algorithmic level:

```
def numPointsInCircle(x1, y1, x2, y2, xl, yl, R):
    R2 = R ** 2
    num = 0
    a = y1 - yl
    b = y2 + 1 - yl
    for x in range(x1 - xl, x2 + 1 - xl):
        R2xxsqrt = (R2 - x ** 2) ** 0.5
        for y in range(a, b):
            if abs(y) <= R2xxsqrt:
                num += 1
    return num
```

On my machine this reduces runtime by up to a factor of five. What I did was mainly avoiding unnecessary redos of the same computations, as well as replacing the square in the if-statement in the inner for-loop by a square root in the outer for-loop, etc...

The code I used to proxy correctness of the optimized version of the function:

```
import numpy as np

n = 42
x1 = np.random.randint(1, 100, n)
y1 = np.random.randint(1, 100, n)
x2 = np.random.randint(101, 200, n)
y2 = np.random.randint(101, 200, n)
xl = np.random.randint(1, 200, n)
yl = np.random.randint(1, 200, n)
R = np.random.randint(1, 200, n)

def numPointsInCircle(x1, y1, x2, y2, xl, yl, R):
    num = 0
    for x in range(x1, x2 + 1):
        for y in range(y1, y2 + 1):
            if (x - xl) ** 2 + (y - yl) ** 2 <= R ** 2:
                num += 1
    return num


def numPointsInCircle2(x1, y1, x2, y2, xl, yl, R):
    R2 = R ** 2
    num = 0
    a = y1 - yl
    b = y2 + 1 - yl
    for x in range(x1 - xl, x2 + 1 - xl):
        R2xxsqrt = (R2 - x ** 2) ** 0.5
        for y in range(a, b):
            if abs(y) <= R2xxsqrt:
                num += 1
    return num


res = []
for i in range(n):
    res.append(numPointsInCircle(x1[i], y1[i], x2[i], y2[i], xl[i], yl[i], R[i]))

res2 = []
for i in range(n):
    res2.append(numPointsInCircle2(x1[i], y1[i], x2[i], y2[i], xl[i], yl[i], R[i]))

assert res == res2
```

I am sure one could optimize this further, e.g. by breaking out of the loops as soon as the condition stops to hold, or also by splitting up each of the outer and inner ranges into two where applicable (i.e. such that the absolute value for each integer occurring in the range (as the only thing that matters due to squaring) is only dealt with once as opposed to possibly twice, namely integers whose inverse also occurs in the range are in the first range, where num is increased by two, and integers whose inverse does not occur in the range are in the second range, where the increment is left at one).